# How to build a dataset for language modeling with the datasets library as with the old TextDataset from the transformers library

Tags: python, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to load a custom dataset that I will then use for language modeling. The dataset consists of a text file that has a whole document in each line, meaning that each line overpasses the normal 512 tokens limit of most tokenizers.

I would like to understand what is the process to build a text dataset that tokenizes each line, having previously split the documents in the dataset into lines of a "tokenizable" size, as the old [TextDataset](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/data/datasets/language_modeling.py) class would do, where you only had to do the following, and a tokenized dataset without text loss would be available to pass to a DataCollator:

```
model_checkpoint = 'distilbert-base-uncased'

from transformers import AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)

from transformers import TextDataset

dataset = TextDataset(
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    file_path="path/to/text_file.txt",
    block_size=512,
)
```

Instead of this way, which is to be deprecated soon, I would like to use the [datasets](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/) library. For now, what I have is the following, which, of course, throws an error because each line is longer than the maximum block size in the tokenizer:

```
import datasets
dataset = datasets.load_dataset('path/to/text_file.txt')

model_checkpoint = 'distilbert-base-uncased'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)

def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples["text"])

tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True, num_proc=4, remove_columns=["text"])
```

So what would be the "standard" way of creating a dataset in the way it was done before but with the datasets lib?

Thank you very much for the help :))

Comment: This actually depends on your task. The tokenizer offers several options like truncation, sliding windows. Just check its [parameters](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.5.1/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.__call__).

Comment: Yeah, but this is a little bit like saying nothing. As I mention before the tokenizer is already being used. The idea is to have the dataset divided in sequences that can then be tokenized, so no information is lost in the process.

Comment: Not sure if I misunderstand you, but what I meant is that you are using the tokenizer with the wrong options for your use case which you still haven't specified (language modeling is pretty broad). What you probably want to use is a sliding window approach and you have to decide what happens with the overflowing tokens by yourself.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for, athough I was having trouble with the specific implementation. I posted an answer bellow with the specifics from the HuggingFace Datasets people :)

Comment: Good that you say here that TextDataset is old. i tried to fix some code for that, only now I know that it is outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer for this question on the [HuggingFace Datasets forum](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/help-understanding-how-to-build-a-dataset-for-language-as-with-the-old-textdataset/5870) by @lhoestq

> Hi !
>
> If you want to tokenize line by line, you can use this:
>
> ```
> max_seq_length = 512
> num_proc = 4
>
> def tokenize_function(examples):
>     # Remove empty lines
>     examples["text"] = [line for line in examples["text"] if len(line) > 0 and not line.isspace()]
>     return tokenizer(
>         examples["text"],
>         truncation=True,
>         max_length=max_seq_length,
>     )
>
> tokenized_dataset = dataset.map(
>     tokenize_function,
>     batched=True,
>     num_proc=num_proc,
>     remove_columns=["text"],
> )
> ```
>
> Though the TextDataset was doing a different processing by
> concatenating all the texts and building blocks of size 512. If you
> need this behavior, then you must apply an additional map function
> after the tokenization:
>
> ```
> # Main data processing function that will concatenate all texts from
> # our dataset and generate chunks of max_seq_length.
> def group_texts(examples):
>     # Concatenate all texts.
>     concatenated_examples = {k: sum(examples[k], []) for k in examples.keys()}
>     total_length = len(concatenated_examples[list(examples.keys())[0]])
>     # We drop the small remainder, we could add padding if the model supported it instead of this drop,
>     # you can customize this part to your needs.
>     total_length = (total_length // max_seq_length) * max_seq_length
>     # Split by chunks of max_len.
>     result = {
>         k: [t[i : i + max_seq_length] for i in range(0, total_length, max_seq_length)]
>         for k, t in concatenated_examples.items()
>     }
>     return result
>
> # Note that with `batched=True`, this map processes 1,000 texts together,
> # so group_texts throws away a remainder for each of those groups of 1,000 texts.
> # You can adjust that batch_size here but a higher value might be slower to preprocess.
>
> tokenized_dataset = tokenized_dataset.map(
>     group_texts,
>     batched=True,
>     num_proc=num_proc,
> )
> ```
>
> This code comes from the processing of the run_mlm.py example script
> of transformers